# Cannot group Apps into folders in my App drawer

Tags: samsung, launcher, android-11, app-drawer, folders

Currently using a Samsung S10e with Android 11.
I Smart-Switch'ed from a Samsung J7 prime with Android 8, a couple of months ago.

I could group apps in my Android 8 by (as best as I remember):

1. From the *Home* screen, swipe from the bottom up. This led me to the
   *App drawer*.
2. If creating a new folder, long press on any icon in the *App drawer* and drop it on top of another app that would share the folder.
3. If adding an icon to an existing folder, long press on the icon and drag-and-drop it on the folder.

Now, when I long press on an icon in the *App drawer* and I start dragging it, the *Home* screen is immediately shown for dropping.
So I can now group icons as above in my *Home*, same as before.
But I cannot do that in the *App drawer*, where I am certain **all** app icons are shown, and thus I am certain all icons are assigned to some folder (or left in the "root" folder).

**Is that grouping still possible in the *App drawer*?**
It [*might* not be possible](https://support.google.com/android/thread/64695648/why-can-t-i-customize-my-app-drawer-in-android-10?hl=en) with the default launcher, but I want to make sure before moving to a different launcher, like Nova.

**Related**:

1. [Folders organization in home screen not always shown](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/244479/folders-organization-in-home-screen-not-always-shown)
2. https://www.theverge.com/2019/3/6/18246685/how-to-organize-android-home-screen
3. https://www.techrepublic.com/article/declutter-your-android-apps-with-nova-launcher/ This suggests you *need* an alternative launcher to allow for grouping icons
4. https://www.wikihow.com/Group-Apps-on-Android This suggests you *don't need* an alternative launcher to allow for grouping icons, although it might be outdated
5. https://www.forbes.com/sites/ewanspence/2016/03/03/google-android-n-app-drawer-removal/?sh=389ec8a53853: "For those not familiar with Android terminology, the home screen is where app icons can be optionally placed when installed, along with any widgets or shortcuts. The app drawer is an icon present on the home screen that opens up a list of every application installed on the phone. This split nature of home screen and an app drawer is one of Android's main points of differentiation with Apple's iOS."

Comment: By "General" screen, I think it's usually called "App launcher" screen. Both home screen and app launcher's behavior depend on the Home app itself. AFAIK, Samsung's own Homescreen app did have such a feature, but I'm not sure with their current Homescreen app though.

Comment: @AndrewT. - I have now learned that the screen with all app icons is called App drawer. I could pull that name from the phone itself, and then I confirmed that in many sources online.

Comment: I think you can't create folders on app drawer(app drawer is a list of all installed apps). But, you can create custom group of app categories in launcher like poco launcher.(while in app drawer swipe to switch between categories )

Comment: Not sure about your specific phone, but what worked for several people is tapping the three dots on the top right of the App Drawer, then "Arrange apps", then drag one app onto another app. Dragging one onto another sometimes requires many attempts.